# how to shadow system boost library?

Tags: c++, python, boost, binding

I was compiling pyrosetta on the cluster(I have no root privilege),pyrosetta requires boost version 1.38,and i install boost 1.38 in my home dir.But the cluster have some version of boost installed in /usr/include/boost/, which is not compatible with pyrosetta code.
Is there any way to shadow the system boost library and use my installed version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the include path and library path to use your own install, instead of the one provided by the system. Here's a [tutorial](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/02wi/unix/g++.html) on this for `g++`.

Comment: As far as I know,gcc will fist try to find the #include header file in system directory, then the user specified dir,so...

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-isystem <dir>` preprocessor option. This shall achieve what you need.

Excerpt from the cpp manpage (which also applies to gcc)

```
-isystem dir

       Search dir for header files, after all directories specified by -I
       but before the standard system directories.  Mark it as a system
       directory, so that it gets the same special treatment as is applied
       to the standard system directories.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I made a mistake, the include dirs specified by -I flag has higher priority than the system ones, so just specify the user install version using -I option will do the trick